# Can't save R notebook because error: "Error creating notebook: 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'. See line 417"

Tags: r, list, markdown, double

I cannot figure out why I'm getting this error. It is preventing me from saving and rendering my notebook. Line 417 looks blank.

[image: Screenshot of error and code]

Copy of code (lines 411-415):

```
CF_full %>% 
  filter(CF_elig == 1) %>% 
  nrow()

nrow(CF_full)
```

I read some other forums and tried this but the same error occurred:

```
CF_full %>% 
  filter(CF_elig == 1) %>% 
  nrow() %>% unlist()

nrow(CF_full) %>% unlist()
```

Comment: (1) `CF_full %>% ... %>% nrow()` is counting the rows but does not filter the data in-place, `CF_full` is not updated. If you want to save the filtered result, then `CF_full <- CF_full %>% filter(CF_elig == 1)`. (2) If you accidentally do `CF_full <- CF_full %>% filter(CF_elig == 1) %>% nrow()`, then `CF_full` will be replaced with an integer, the number of rows after the filter ... and you will need to regenerate `CF_full` completely. I suggest you keep `%>% nrow()` _out_ of your pipeline.

Comment: I'm not trying to filter the data in-place or update CF_full.  I'm simply trying to get a count of those with the indicator CF_elig.  Would count() be a better function to use? And is that preventing my notebook from saving?  I use the technique throughout my code and it doesn't give me any issues. Thanks!

Comment: One thought: of you type `filter` (nothing else) and hit enter (on the console), does it say it is from `namespace:dplyr` or `namespace:stats`?

Comment: It says namespace:dplyr.

Comment: Okay. What's in the code block immediately below line 418?

Comment: That's where I have the text "This method calculates..." and then some inline code, which is the same code that's in the code chunk (or I guess close, it takes the two numbers in the code chunk and divides them go get a percentage):

This method calculates that `r percent(CF_full %>% filter(CF_elig == 1) %>% nrow()/nrow(CF_full))`

Comment: I cannot reproduce this with a partial document and assumed data. For instance, I can replace your three expressions there with `mtcars %>% filter(cyl == 4) %>% nrow()`, then `nrow(mtcars)`, and finally `scales::percent(mtcars %>% filter(cyl == 4) %>% nrow() / nrow(mtcars))`, and all three execute without an error like that.

Comment: Okay, so you're not sure where the error is coming from? Like I said, I've done similar code throughout my file and it works fine. I can try to tweak it just for this instance and hope everything saves okay. Thanks for looking into it!

Comment: Just to follow up, I realized the error was coming from a typo in the inline code *following* the code on line 418. So the error message was pretty misleading pointing me to line 417, but glad I figured it out.

Comment: I'm so glad you were able to figure it out! Now we all know that the error line numbers can be off by one (or more), so mostly a hint. Great!